# How to create custom 404 error page for all users in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to create 404 error pages but it should be usable for all of users, If I use ErrorDocument 404 /404.php it will display "*Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*" on users web site, How to create it without placing 404.php in every users documentroot?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your apache with rewrite rule as above:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/customerrors/page-404.html
# or maybe .php if you want some smarts in that page?
```

but also put a system-wide alias in place for the /customerrors/ path

```
Alias /customerrors /var/www/html/custom-errors/
<Directory /var/www/html/custom-errors/>
  # make sure the location can be used to serve files
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You'll just have to be a little careful to not override a website-local URL.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your apache with rewrite rule

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/custom/page-404.html
```

Comment: thank you for fast response :) but it will redirect all users 404 to domain.com? is there a way to not redirect to other domain but stay in users domain?